# ValueChanges doesn't fire when combining nested form groups in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Consider the following scenario:

There are two form groups ("address" and "customer") with one form control (text field) each. They are reused and combined in two other form groups ("debit" and "credit').

Motivation is that I might want to combine different form groups for different forms (for example, some group needs address group and some other doesn't), or introduce different validators for different form groups.

Code:

**app.component.html:**

```
<div class="container">

    <form [formGroup]="customer">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>E-mail</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="email">
        </div>
    </form>

    <form [formGroup]="address">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Street</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="street">
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from "@angular/core";
import {FormGroup, FormControl} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "app-form",
  templateUrl: "app.component.html",
})
export class AppComponent {

  address = new FormGroup({
    street: new FormControl(),
  });

  customer = new FormGroup({
    email: new FormControl(),
  });

  debit = new FormGroup({
    customer: this.customer,
    address: this.address,
  });

  credit = new FormGroup({
    customer: this.customer,
    address: this.address,
  });

  ngOnInit() {

    // this will not fire on change
    this.debit.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log);

    // this will fire on change
    this.credit.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log);
  }

}
```

The problem is that whenever I perform changes in the child group (say, type something in the street field), only the last `this.credit.valueChanges` observable fires a new value, the former `this.debit.valueChanges` does not see the change, even though address is it's child group.

So I wanted to ask what is the reason for this behavior and, if this behavior is desired, how do I implement my use case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Each control has only one parent

Comment: @yurzui Would it make sense to try to override this behavior to allow multiple parents?